# How to run SlaveOk in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose, slave

How to call SlaveOK on query in Mongoose?

for example, I have this:

```
SiteModel.find({}, function(err, docs) { .... } );
```

Should I do this???

```
SiteModel.slaveOK().find({}, function(err,docs) { ... } );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the official example from the Mongoose.js website:

```
Model
.where('age').gte(25)
.where('tags').in(['movie', 'music', 'art'])
.select('name', 'age', 'tags')
.skip(20)
.limit(10)
.asc('age')
.slaveOk()
.hint({ age: 1, name: 1 })
.run(callback);
```

So I guess your example above would probably work, but do it like so:

```
Model.find(conditions).slaveOk().run(callback);
```

Answer (score 7):

`mongoose.Query.slaveOk` has been deprecated in favour of `mongoose.Query.read(readPreference)`. [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-read)

So, to iterate on the example above:

```
Model
.where('age').gte(25)
.where('tags').in(['movie', 'music', 'art'])
.select('name', 'age', 'tags')
.skip(20)
.limit(10)
.asc('age')
.read('secondaryPreferred')
.hint({ age: 1, name: 1 })
.run(callback);
```

Comment: There's an error in the spelling, the critical line should be `.read('secondaryPreferred')` with a double-"r".

Comment: Note that `mongoose.Query.read()` is misleading: `read()` is not a static method of `Query`, only of `Query` instances.